# Custom field form type required not saving on Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am creating custom field form for menu item on Joomla 2.5.
The problem is upon saving it is returning error "Field required: Template" even though there is value in it.

This is the code for the field:

```
jimport('joomla.html.html');
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldTemplate extends JFormField {

protected $type = 'template';

protected function getInput() {
    $html = '<select>  <option value="1">Template 1</option> </select>';
    return $html;
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="Display Template">
        <message>
            <![CDATA[Select Template to Display]]>
        </message>
    </layout>

    <fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/fields">
         <fields name="request">
        <fieldset name="request">
                     <field name="id" type="template" label="Template"
                           description="Select template to display"
                           required="true" />
        </fieldset>
     </fields>
    </fieldset>

</metadata>
```

To clarify yes "com_mycomponent" is the component name.

Unfortunately the Joomla documentation is not the best out there...
What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot a name of the field
`<select name="'.$this->name.'">`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Can't believe I missed this... Thank you for your time!